# Using Tiled app to create Cocos2d .plist

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, format

I'm trying to use the Tiled application on OSX to create a tile background for a 2d iPhone game I'm working on. I need some way to export the completed background to a .plist file so that I can use it directly with cocos2d and the app I'm writing. Unfortunately, the only export options available are:

.dat
.txt
.json
.lua
.wlk

Is there any way to easily convert any of the above formats to a more usable .plist format? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean the [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org)? Cocos2d iPhone supports the TMX maps natively. Just save the TMX and load it with the CCTMXTiledMap class.